# BLE not a valid peripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Sometimes in random moments (usually after background disconnect) I have a strange bug with connection

```
WARNING: <CBPeripheral: 0x1c4109ea0, identifier = 6040FFF8-6E53-4776-ABF7-9632093B2DB5, name = XXXXXXXX, state = connecting> is not a valid peripheral
```

I checked connection status on BLE device and app was connected but didn't subscribe for notifications. On app, state was connecting. The only way to reconnect properly after this bug is to close and open app again.
What can I do to prevent this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, if you are connecting any BLE device multiple times, then before connecting device again it should be disconnected. As From your scenario, it seems that you are connecting a BLE device again n again without disconnecting it.